# Get some data which corresponds to the maximum date

Tags: sql

I have these 3 tables:

```
Table ORG:
   Fields:historyid, personid
Table PERSON:
   Fields: id
Table HISTORY:
   Fields: id,date,personid
```

Both HISTORY and ORG are linked to PERSON with an 1:N relationship. Also, ORG is linked to HISTORY with an 1:N relationship. **I want to get from table ORG for each person just one row: this which corresponds to the HISTORY row with the highest date.** The following SQL gives the highest date for a certain person. However, I do not know how to combine this with the above requirement.

```
SELECT ash1.id                  
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM history a WHERE  a.personid=person.id) ash1          
LEFT JOIN    
(SELECT * FROM history b WHERE  b.personid=person.id) ash2
ON ash1.personid=ash2.personid
AND ash1.date < ash2.date
WHERE ash2.date IS NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this, depending on the database.  However, your data structure is awkward.  Why does `org` have `historyid`? That doesn't really make sense to me.

In any case, based on your description, this should work:

```
select o.*, h.*
from org o join
    history h
    on h.personid = o.personid
where h.date = (select max(h2.date)
                from history h2
                where h2.personid = h.personid
               );
```

You might want to start the `from` clause as:

```
from (select distinct personid from org) o
```

So, you only get one person, if they are repeated in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    o.historyid AS o_hist,
    o.personid AS o_per,
    h.id AS h_id,
    MAX(h.date) AS h_date,
    h.personid AS h_person
FROM
    org o
        LEFT JOIN
    person p ON p.id = o.personid
        LEFT JOIN
    history h ON h.id = o.historyid AND h.personid = p.id
GROUP BY o_per
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query..

```
 ;WITH_CTE_HighestHistory
 AS (SELECT PersonID,MAX([Date]) HDate
     FROM History
     GROUP BY PersonID)
 SELECT org.*,h.*
 FROM org o
    LEFT JOIN History h ON o.Historyid=h.Id and o.PersonID=h.PersonId
    INNER JOIN WITH_CTE_HighestHistory ch ON h.Personid=ch.Personid and h.[Date]=ch.[Date]
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Person p WHERE p.Id=o.PersonID )
```